# Return function value in lodash templates

Tags: javascript, html, templates, backbone.js, lodash

I am using lodash templates to render html templates client side. There are many html templates which are being repeated. So, I decided to call the repeating template in another template. For example:

#### dummy.html

```
<%= _.template(templates['button'])({ title: "click me" }) %>
```

The above approach works but as I am calling `_.template` to render a button again and again, I thought to make a global function as shown below:

#### dummy.js

```
var sb = {
    setButton: function(data){
        data = data || {};
        return _.template(templates['button'])(data);
    },
    /* other functions */
}
```

and then call in the `dummy.html` as:

```
<%= sb.setButton({ title: "click me" }) %>
```

But this isn't working. (*It just doesn't render*)

What I am doing wrong here?

**EDIT**:

I placed `console.log(this)` in `setButton` function. it was not logging anything in chrome console. Then I removed `=` from lodash template syntax, then it logged `sb` global variable.

```
<% sb.setButton({ title: "click me" }) %>
```

But still the above one is not rendering the button.

Comment: What does `console.log(this)` print, if added to your `dummy.js` function (compared to the original function)?

Comment: @royhowie I added explanation in my post edit section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your compiled templates don't know what `sb` is. Assuming you're calling your main template with something like `_.template(src)()`, Lodash chokes on it with an error looking like `ReferenceError: sb is not defined`. Pass your partials hash as an option and you will get your button:

```js
var templates = {
    button: '<button><%= title %></button>'
};
var sb = {
    setButton: function(data){
        data = data || {};
        return _.template(templates['button'])(data);
    }
};

var src = '<%= sb.setButton({ title: "click me" }) %>'
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = _.template(src)({sb: sb});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
<div id='result'></div>
```

If you prefer to have you partials directly available without passing them to your template, attach your global to `_`, for example as `_.sb`:

```js
var templates = {
    button: '<button><%= title %></button>'
};
_.sb = {
    setButton: function(data){
        data = data || {};
        return _.template(templates['button'])(data);
    }
};

var src = '<%= _.sb.setButton({ title: "click me" }) %>'
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = _.template(src)();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
<div id='result'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need extend data pass to template with `sb`, some like this:

```
var sb = {
    setButton: function(data){
        data = data || { name: "default" };
        return _.template("<%= name %>")(data);
    },
}

var tmpl = _.template( '<%= setButton({ name: name }) %>' );
var data = _.extend({name:"click"}, {sb});
tmpl(data)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/stdob/bjdw63wb/2/